# Where else to find Bruce Fox-Lefriche's arr. of Bach's BWV 565 for solo violin?

Tags: instrumental

I'm trying to find Bruce Fox-Lefriche: *Sonata for Violin "A Tribute to Bach"*, also known as *Sonata for solo violin, attributed to J.S. Bach - BWW 565* (in WorldCat).

Here's what I've found so far:

[Lore from 2005 has it](http://www.maestronet.com/forum/index.php?/topic/260361-toccata-and-fugue/) that this arrangement was available on net4music.com sometime after 2000. Unfortunately, net4music stopped selling music in October 2002.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toccata_and_Fugue_in_D_minor,_BWV_565), the piece was composed in 2004. That's wrong: there's a [German article in NMZ](https://www.nmz.de/artikel/neues-altes-vom-beruehmtesten-orgelstueck) from Oct. 2000 that refers to the piece. The source of the error could be that 2004 was a year that Fox-Lefriche published an article in Strings, titled *The greatest violin sonata that J.S. Bach never wrote*. An article that I disagree with - as an aside.

I've been able to confirm from the archive.org snapshots that net4music had Mr. Fox-Lefriche listed in their catalog prior to their acquisition (by Makemusic!?). I couldn't confirm there that they had the particular piece available, though. But not all is lost: the National Library of Israel (NLI) [has the piece in its holdings](http://primo.nli.org.il/primo_library/libweb/action/dlDisplay.do?vid=NLI&docId=NNL_ALEPH002220600), and lists the year of publication as 1999, and the publisher as "Net music; Editions musicales regia; no. 5631".

net4music got acquired IIRC in 1999-2000 by MakeMusic!, better known for Finale etc. The latter presumably didn't want to be in music publishing business, and they shuttered net4music in Oct 2002, and parts of net4music catalog to sheetmusicdirect. Alas, sheetmusicdirect doesn't list anything by Mr. Fox-Lefriche :( I've sent them a query about it through the "Contact Us" form.

There is a performance by Sergei Krylow [available on YouTube](https://youtu.be/R_tu63ypB6I). As a last resort, I'll work off that and transcribe it, but I'd much rather just obtain the arrangement that someone somewhere must have - or so I hope.

Save for a way to buy it or find the arrangement in a library, does anyone know how to perhaps get a hold of Mr. Fox-Lefriche himself? He has no online presence :(

A cursory check in other music libraries with online catalogs yields no other results. It looks like the only copy in the world is held by the NLI. That might as well be on the Mars for me :(

Comment: Hi! Are you expecting more answers or more details? Please accept the answer if it is okay for you. Regards.

Comment: Any insight concerning publishing date and publisher would also be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Bruce Fox le Friche is on the [teaching staff](http://crd.bourgenbresse-agglomeration.fr/index.php/presentation/les-enseignants) of the Conservatoire de Bourg-en-Bresse. See under "Pratiques collectives vocales et instrumentales" : he is one of the organisers of the string orchestra.
I was led to this by [this other post](http://www.pavilek.fr/crbst_102.html) - I assume there is only one violin teacher of this name....

[Contact details for the Conservatoire](http://crd.bourgenbresse-agglomeration.fr/index.php/faq)